# Is the cubic formula numerically unstable?

Tags: polynomials, number-systems, cubics

Are there numerical rounding issues in using the cubic formula to find roots of cubic equations?  Similarly with the quartic formula?

I do know for the quadratic formula to solve $ax^2+bx+c = 0$ that you use the formulas $x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ or $x = \frac{2c}{-b \mp \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}$ so that the numerator or denominator respectively are chosen so that they are the sum of two terms with the same sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could certainly be.

You have

$$S = \sqrt [3] {R + \sqrt{Q^3 + R^2}}$$
and
$$T = \sqrt [3] {R - \sqrt{Q^3 + R^2}}$$

so if $Q$ is small compared
with $R$,
there could be trouble.

The $\sqrt{}$s could be computed
safely in that case,
as in the quadratic case,
by
$a-\sqrt{a^2+b}
=(a-\sqrt{a^2+b})\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2+b}}{a+\sqrt{a^2+b}}
=\frac{-b}{a+\sqrt{a^2+b}}
$.

I wouldn't be surprised
if standard libraries
took these kind
of precautions.

Comment: Do any standard libraries actually use the cubic or quartic formulas?  Or do they use some kind of numerical technique (like finding eigenvalues of the companion matrix)?

Comment: If they used the formulae, I certainly hope they practice safe computation.

Comment: I would not be surprised if many standard libraries use *regula falsi* to get a real zero, since it's known (if I recall correctly) to be quite well behaved.

Comment: If the libraries have good numerical methods for solving higher-degree polynomials, I don't see why they would bother trying to use the cubic or quartic formula for finding numerical solutions.

Comment: Here's a link to matlab where they say that "Note that these solution formulas are well known to be numerically unstable."
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/151683-solving-a-cubic-equation

Comment: Some sites produce perfect radical solutions, so I doubt that they could have used numerical techniques.

Comment: Here, Wolfram Alpha appears to use your precautions.  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3%2B2x%5E2%2B3x%2B4%3D0