# Studying math at Grade 8

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, reference-request, soft-question

I'm currently studying in Grade 8 and I took a huge interest in math. I'm still learning algebra and I was currently wondering if I could start at least the most basic concepts of calculus. I have not taken trigonometry and I was just wondering. Is it possible or is it too early for me?
PS: This is my first question here! Thank you!

Comment: Trigonometry is definitely not necessary, though it may be helfpful

Comment: you should learn basic concepts of algebra  before taking calculus.

Comment: Yes, it can be a bit algebra intensive if you don't know what your doing.

Comment: While I am very much glad for your enthusiasm to learn, I must vote this question as off-topic.  It is not actually about math.

Comment: Now, I can tell you that you can learn tricky algebraic manipulations simply be listening in on the `(algebra-precalculus)` tag.

Comment: Since you probably want a peek at what calculus is like yourself: [here are some notes.](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/CalcI.aspx)

Comment: Trigonometry would definitely be adequate for 8th-grade, as it would allow you to use at the same time tools from geometry and algebra, and would introduce you to some basic functions of calculus. It leads to rather concrete problems too (geodesy, astronomy, surveying...).

Comment: Algebra I or Algebra II?

Comment: You can use [trigonometry algebraically](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1940720/trigonometric-quadratic-formula-and-other-trig-solutions-for-roots-of-polynomia).

Comment: @SimpleArt It's was a rather standard tool before calculators and computers: since the only computational tools were slide rules and log tables, trigonometric functions were heavily used in all kind of algebraic operations, including computing roots of polynomials of degree 2 or 3. There are several articles on JSTOR about this, some of them freely available now, and many old trigonometry books (19th century) are really worth a look (try Internet Archive for instance)

Comment: @SimpleArt What does it mean to use trigonometry algebraically? I clicked on your heading but I did not get what did it mean expect for the quadratic equation.

Comment: @galaxymcpvp Sometimes, when you have a problem, you can solve it using method 1, method 2, or method 3.  But often times methods 1/2 are not good for the problem, hence we would use method 3.  Often times the other method requires knowledge in different fields of mathematics.

Comment: As you embark on pursuing mathematics on your on, I would suggest considering the full breadth of mathematics. For example, in terms of applicability to my engineering-type jobs, a working knowledge of the following areas has proven most relevant to me: complex numbers, linear algebra, analytic geometry, trigonometry, numerical analysis. There is lots of fascinating stuff in all these areas for the self-learner.

Comment: @njuffa I second you on numerical analysis. I would add discrete mathematics. They both allow experimenting with a computer, and one may learn much this way. And even in 8th grade, it's not completely extraordinary to compute an area by rectangle or trapezoidal method, preparing for integration later.

Comment: Interestingly, that's _exactly_ what I did many years ago - I started learning calculus on my own in 8. grade. It turned out very successful, but ymmv. I'd say if you find it interesting, go for it.

Comment: I would say that its up to you...but first you should try and master some fundamental concepts of maths such as polynomials, number theory and solving inequations, equations as well as the concept of limits....before starting calculus. Also trigonometry and a little bit of coordinate geometry would be a bonus.....keep practicing and good luck!!

Comment: I'd say the only absolutely necessary requirement to learn Calculus is Algebra.  Everything else can be picked up as you go along.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the [online notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/CalcI.aspx) I personally used to get through Calculus.  I will note that it requires Algebra, so you definitely need to be comfortable with the subject.  As a hint at what Calculus is like, consider the following:

$$y=\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}$$

Most likely you will be faced with the question "What is $y$ when $x\approx1$?"  If you plug in $x=1$, you will get division by $0$ error, but,

$$\begin{array}{c|c}x&y\\\hline0.9&1.9\\\hline0.99&1.99\\\hline1&?\\\hline1.01&2.01\\\hline1.1&2.1\end{array}$$

You can get a good picture of what the answer is, but Calculus will make this concept rigorous with algebra and limits, which is the first topic.  The answer to the above question is indeed $y=2$.

---

Trigonometry is rather simple as far as definitions:

[image]

Those are the basic formulas of trigonometry.  You should already know a fourth equation:

$$a^2+o^2=h^2$$

Such simple triangles will get increasingly complicated in how you will use them, but it is good to know *what* they are, which isn't too much at all.  Just draw some triangles, find the side lengths, and you get $\sin,\cos,\tan$.

---

There is a topic in Algebra that I want to make note of, and you should be coming close to it.  It is complex numbers.  See that

$$x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$$

But there is no such normal solution to

$$x^2+1=(x+?)(x+?)$$

If we let such a number exist, it shall have to be $i=\sqrt{-1}$, which is quite absurd, but anyways,

$$x^2+1=(x+i)(x-i)$$

You may ask what this has to do with any of the above, and I will simply tell you there are connections between this and triangles, and secondly, that if you allow such numbers, calculus can be easier sometimes.

To give you the connection, take $1+i$.  Then draw it on a complex plane.  Then take $(1+i)^2$ and draw it on the graph.  Same with $(1+i)^3$ etc. etc. until you feel satisfied.  Then, will you be able to see any triangles?  Mainly, can you find triangles that start from $(0,0)$ and connect to each point?  What can you deduce about angles?

Then ask if it is reasonable to take the Algebra path to find $(1+i)^{100}$ or to use triangles.

---

Now, if you happen to be interested in coding, I recommend numerical analysis.  As a sneak peak:

Find $\sqrt2$ in decimal form:

$$a_0=1\\a_1=\frac{(a_0)^2+2}{2\times a_0}=\frac32=1.5\\a_2=\frac{(a_1)^2+2}{2\times a_1}=\frac{17}{12}=1.41666\\a_3=\dots=\frac{577}{408}=1.41421$$

Which is equivalent to $\sqrt2$ out 5 decimal places.  If you keep doing this forever, you will get $\sqrt2$ out as many decimals you desire.  Best done with a program.

---

I will also recommend finishing Algebra early.  Find a book to read so that you can get a good head start.

---

Discrete mathematics are also a good place.  An example of something simple:

$$1+2+3+\dots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}2$$

I personally find the topic interesting, and it connects to calculus in some ways.

Comment: Very well written answer!

Answer (score 1):

Learn basic facts about quadratic equations, solving them, roots of polynomials, multiplying and dividing polynomials with remainders. And definitely trigonometry. In a strict sense trigonometry is  unnecessary for development of calculus, but knowing that well is a huge plus and recommended.

Also basic things about two-dimensional analytic (co-ordinate ) geometry: equations of lines, circles, parabolas their tangents.

These will provide you enough examples, and enough problems to practice in calculus.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I had faced a very similar situation years back, here's my advice for you.

- If you start studying basics of Calculus from $8th$ grade itself, that won't be problem. But you'll encounter a situation where you would need to deal with trigonometric and logarithmic functions, especially the former one. So be sure you study the basics, and if you don't, you'll have to return there definitely someday.
- If you still have the interest, try the book *Calculus for Dummies* , that will provide you a nice mental platform for further studies.
- Solve as much problems as possible. Calculus is vast, and encapsulates much of math, be sure to prepare early and smart.

**Book Recommendations:**

1. SL Loney, Trigonometry.
2. Hall and Knight, Higher Algebra.
3. Problems in Mathematics, Govorov.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks! I'll probably study more algebra and trigonometry since I've only started quadratic equations and simplifying quadratic expressions.

Comment: Recommend *Algebra for Dummies* first.

Comment: @SimpleArt He said he's learning Algebra, so he doesn't need it, probably.

Comment: @SwapnilDas Didn't see his comment by the time I finished my comment.  And its still good to finish Algebra early before Calc.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you'd be better off learning your current curriculum first. I was in the exact same position in 8th grade ( for physics though; I wanted to learn tensor analysis in order to tackle general relativity...finally did it in 10th :)), and I learnt this the hard way.Reason- Math is pretty vast. When you really reach a position to pursue the more intricate details, you will need to choose between the many branches it offers(say, topology or number theory); and in order to really realise what you ACTUALLY want, you should be in a better position to appreciate all of them. I would suggest that right now you focus more on building your intuition rather than romping through textbooks. If I may, I'd like to suggest a few books you can use, preferably in the SAME order.

Hall and Knight - Higher Algebra

SL Loney-Trigonometry; Coordinate geometry

IA Maron- Calculus of one variable

David M Burton-Number theory ( one of my favourites)

Walter Rudin - Mathematical analysis ( Goldberg works too)

Coddington- Ordinary differential equations

Gillespie- Partial differentiation

Widder - Advanced calculus

Phew! But don't get overwhelmed; this will require at least 2-3 years, so take it one step at a time. This was just to give you a ready reference and show you how vast math really is...any questions, fire away!

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! I also like physics especially quantum mechanics and that is why I was asking requirements for calculus.

Comment: Good to know....just so you know, Griffith's book on quantum electrodynamics and quantum mechanics are pretty cool...especially for beginners. But go through Feynman lectures first-my all time favourites :)

Comment: @galaxymcpvp Good luck good sir.  Learn all the things for your dreams and be the 16 year old quantum mechanic!